# Single Sign-On with Windows Authentication in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using .Net framework 3.5
IIS 8.5
Visual studio 2008 32bit application
Windows server 2012 R2

I have configured my application with Single Sign-On with Windows Authentication in IIS. When I am trying to access the application using the link https://abcxyz, every time it is prompting for credentials to enter for windows. In my development local machine it is not prompting to enter the credentials but when I deploy in windows server 2012 R2 server it is prompting me for credentials.Now I am looking for the solution where users should be able to navigate to the login page without prompting to enter the credentials for windows. I would highly appreciate if you could guide us in resolving this issue.

In IIS, I had enabled the windows authentication.

Thanks...

Comment: Is it Web Forms, MVC, something else? How did you configure SSO such as Owin Middleware auth or [IIS cmd line](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(v=ws.10).aspx)?

Comment: Yes it is Web forms.I had disabled the forms authentication and enabled the windows authentication.I had configured SSO through IIS but not cmd line.

Comment: [Kentor](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/issues/157) might do it but you would need an ADFS/Saml2 server to handle the SSO however I think Kentor was designed with [newer tech](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/issues/157).